# Extending a layover to the next day

Tags: air-travel, layovers, stopovers, connecting-flights

Planning out my next vacation, I found out that the cheapest flight from my city (A) to my destination (C) happens to have a two-hour layover in an airport near one of my closest friends (B). By searching for the same flights earlier the next day, I found out that the entire trip can be bought for the same price the next day, with the friend to destination (B-C) leg a few hours earlier.

What I'm trying to do is mix and match the flight legs from the identically priced two days, so A-B happens on the first day and B-C happens on the second day, giving me 21 hours with my friend. But, whenever I try searching for the flights separately, or as a multi-city trip, or using a number of different flight booking sites, the price seems to jump from around $600 round trip to around $1100 round trip. Is there an easy way of extending this layover from 2 to 21 hours at the same price, given I have the flight numbers in hand?

P.S. The flights are all KLM/Air France partnered flights, and the flights are indeed international.

Comment: Per Itais answer. ITA matrix can specifically search for this and price it out. Use the stopover airport in "routing controls" and the keyword "minconnect" in as extension.  Or just add your detaiils and I do the search for you.

Answer (score 3):

The Multi-City option is always more expensive and one ways often are too. Since your planned stop is less than 24h that will count as a stop-over and you should be able to get a single ticket for this.

When I have done this, I usually search a few OTA such as Expedia, Kayak and SkyScanner and sort by total duration, this usually gets me quite a few choices with a long stopover. Try it out.

When this fails, I go directly to the airline website and see if they will let me construct that itinerary. In the event this fails too, I have done a phone booking and usually got the same price as with a short stop-over plus a $25-50 phone-booking fee. All in all you still save money compared to other options.

Something that I have never tried and might help is [Matrix](https://matrix.itasoftware.com/). If you can search it and get the flights you want by putting your constraints, then you can take the output fare construction and use it to book your flight either with a travel agent or the recent [BookWithMatrix](https://bookwithmatrix.com/) site.